# SQL: Taking one column from two tables and putting them into one predefined table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Just a little bug off my shoulder, but for what I'm using this code for, it is *not* the end of the world if this one doesn't get answered. To preface, a few things: I know this is *entirely improper*, I know this should never be used -- let alone, done -- in a production environment, and I know that the root of this operation is totally unconventional, but I'm asking anyway:

If I have two tables with a set of values that I am looking to grab and put into one other, combined and predefined table, side by side, how might I do that?

Right now, I have two statements doing

```
INSERT INTO table ('leftCol') SELECT NAME FROM smolT1 ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 3
INSERT INTO table ('rightCol') SELECT NAME FROM smolT2 ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 3
```

but, as one would imagine, that query ends up with something like...

```
leftCol      | rightCol
Jack         | 
James        | 
John         |
             | Jill
             | Justina
             | Jesebelle
```

and of course, it would be much more preferred if the left and right column lined up, though, for the sake of gathering just those six records, I suppose it is not too big of a concern.

To add on, yes, these two tables do have a `NAME` in common, but with how I am querying them, they are totally irrelevant one another and *should not* be associated with one another, just displayed side by side.

I am simply curious as to whether or not one query would get these two unrelated queries to work together and print neatly into a form or if I just have to live with this data looking like this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent versions of SQLite support window functions.  This allows you to do:

```
select min(name1) as name1, min(name2) as name2
from ((select name as name1, null as num2 row_number() over (order by name) as seqnum
       from smolt1
       where name is not null
      ) union all
      (select null, name, row_number() over (order by name) as seqnum
       from smolt2
       where name is not null
      )
     ) lr
group by seqnum;
```